# Asynchronous updating DIV layer without AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Is there any way to update a HTML DIV layer in ASP.NET/C# for every 2 seconds without using AJAX triggers. Preferably using JavaScripts (Major priority) or jQuery (If not possible with JavaScripts).

Comment: update the DIV with what? You need to give more information for this question.

Comment: Do you mean by update, to retreive new data from a server, or do an update with data loaded initial? Why do you want to avoid Ajax?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. There is nothing you can do with jQuery that you cannot do without it. *Ajax* stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, and is just a name for a way of communication between the client and the server.

Comment: @JohnP, Tilman - Sorry, I have to update DIV with Server function. I coded to retrieve new data from server under timer tick. Now, I don't want to use Update Panel's content template. So, I need some other way to update DIV.

Answer (score 0):

In first - jQuery is still javascript because is written in that language.

Assume, you would to change text/html inside a DIV.
We have a html:

```
<div id='divId'> </div>
```

And by script would be to change the contents of div.

```
var textOrHtml = "whatever, you can put here also < a href='#'> html </a>";

//without jquery
document.getElementById( "divId" ).innerHTML = textOrHtml;

// by jquery
$( "#divId" ).html( textOrHtml );

</script>
```

If data which you like to update comes from server...  without ajax cannot do that, but is one solution but is  very paintless - sockets uses  from  e.g. flash action script

Comment: Not do without ajax if data must comes from server and a replacement will be without reload page

Answer (score 0):

if you have to update div with data from server. you have to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to update a portion of your page without using AJAX although I don't understand why you would do it this way:

Inside your div, you have to use an [iframe](http://www.htmlquick.com/es/reference/tags/iframe.html) you can style your iframe to have the size you want.
You'll point that iframe into your dinamic page (the script you created) and you have to make that script output HTML code, the HTML code that will be shown on your iframe (which would look like a DIV on your page).

There are 2 way I think you can use to update your iframe:

1- Using javascript, you can probably do something like:

```
function Reload () {
var f = document.getElementById('iframe1');
f.src = f.src;
}
```

2- Using the meta refresh tag. This tag will have to be on the HTML generated on your script. More information [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm)

Hope that this gives you a notch in the right direction. If you have further questions, let me know...